# How do I print latex from a code block in Google Colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, google-colaboratory

In Jupyter, I can write:

```
    d=sqrt(2+3)
    show(d)
```

And it will print the square root of 5 symbolically, using the symbol for square root.

How do I print symbolic LaTeX-formatted output from code blocks in Google Colab?

Answer (score 3):

You could try using calls to the `Math` function like this.

```
from IPython.display import display, Math
latex = r'$\alpha=\Omega^4'
Math(latex)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but note my variable 'd' is a float, not a string. I've updated my question to reflect more precisely the functionality that exists in Jupyter, but seemingly not in Google Colab.

Comment: OK - please edit your original question with the details rather than providing an answer so that others don't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a Jupyter Notebook with SageMath. Which is apparently different to every other type of Jupyter Notebook. It seems the function "show()" belongs to the module "sage", which cannot be imported into Google Colab. Instead of Google Colab, I've had to use cocalc.com which allows me to use a sage kernel.